# Changing / Positioning Image Rollover Link

Tags: html, css

Having problems implementing this mega menu only just using html and css.  It's very close.  To replicate, go to Products/Mega Items and then either "Test 1" or "Test 2".

I want the image to change when hovering over "Test 1" or "Test 2" but am having problems positioning it on different screen sizes.

I've tried various css settings; absolute, pixels or % but it's not working on different resolutions.  I do have it disabled within mobile (ideal)

It SHOULD look similar to this: 
https://codepen.io/arjunamgain/pen/YXBeLJ

If using this as an example, Hover over "Mega Menu", then "Mobile".  I'd like the image on the left to change accordingly.  ie, when hovering over "mobile", I can have a mobile image.  When hovering over "computer", I can have a computer image.

My code is at: https://codepen.io/codewoed/pen/rbyRWE and i can get the images to change, though my alignment is off with different screen resolutions.

```css
  body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font: 300 14px/18px Roboto;
 background-image: url('../images/texture.png');
 } 
 *,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before {
  content: '';
  display: table
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  display: block
}
ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
a, a:hover, a.active, a:active, a:visited, a:focus{
 color:#fefefe;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.content{
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.exo-menu{
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 position:relative;
 background: #fff;
}
.exo-menu > li { display: inline-block;float:left;}
.exo-menu > li > a{
 color: #2e3192;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border-right: 1px #FAFAFA dotted;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
 -moz-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
 -o-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
 transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
}
.exo-menu > li > a.active,
.exo-menu > li > a:hover,
li.drop-down ul > li > a:hover{
 background:#009FE1;
 color:#fff;
}
.exo-menu i {
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  line-height: 20px !important;
}
li.drop-down,
.flyout-right,
.flyout-left{position:relative;}
li.drop-down:before {
  content: "\f103";
  color: #fff;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
li.drop-down>ul{
 left: 0px;
 min-width: 230px;

}
.drop-down-ul{display:none;}
.flyout-right>ul,
.flyout-left>ul{
  top: 0;
  min-width: 230px;
  display: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #365670;
  }

li.drop-down>ul>li>a,
.flyout-right ul>li>a ,
.flyout-left ul>li>a {
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 padding: 20px 22px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #365670;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted #547787;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
 -moz-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
 -o-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
 transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
}
.flyout-right ul>li>a ,
.flyout-left ul>li>a {
 border-bottom: 1px dotted #B8C7BC;
}


/*Flyout Mega*/
.flyout-mega-wrap {
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 left: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 display:none;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 15px;
 min-width: 742px;

}
h4.row.mega-title {
  color:#eee;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 }
.flyout-mega ul > li > a {
  font-size: 90%;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
}
.flyout-mega ul > li > a:hover,
.flyout-mega ul > li > a:active,
.flyout-mega ul > li > a:focus{
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color: #ccc !important
}
/*mega menu*/

.mega-menu {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  display:none;
  padding-top: 0;
  min-height: 100%;

}
h4.row.mega-title {
  color: #eee;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #547787;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: #365670
  }
 .mega-menu ul li a {
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 90%;
  display: block;
}
ul.stander li a {
    padding: 3px 0px;
}

ul.description li {
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    line-height: 8px;
}

ul.description li span {
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 85%;
}
a.view-more{
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin-top:15px;
  background-color: #009FE1;
  padding: 2px 10px !important;
  line-height: 21px !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
}
a.view-more:hover{
 color:#fff;
 background:#0DADEF;
}
ul.icon-des li a i {
    color: #fff;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #009FE1;
    line-height: 35px !important;
}

ul.icon-des li {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}
/*Blog DropDown*/
.Blog{
 left:0;
 display:none;
 color:#fefefe;
 padding-top:15px;
 background:#547787;
 padding-bottom:15px;
}
.Blog .blog-title{
 color:#fff;
 font-size:15px;
 text-transform:uppercase;

}
.Blog .blog-des{
 color:#ccc;
 font-size:90%;
 margin-top:15px;
}
.Blog a.view-more{
 margin-top:0px;
}
/*Images*/
.Images{
 left:0;
   width:100%;
  display:none;
 color:#fefefe;
 padding-top:15px;
 background:#547787;
 padding-bottom:15px;
}
.Images h4 {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
/*common*/
.flyout-right ul>li>a ,
.flyout-left ul>li>a,
.flyout-mega-wrap,
.mega-menu{
 background-color: #547787;
}

/*hover*/
.Blog:hover,
.Images:hover,
.mega-menu:hover,
.drop-down-ul:hover,
li.flyout-left>ul:hover,
li.flyout-right>ul:hover,
.flyout-mega-wrap:hover,
li.flyout-left a:hover +ul,
li.flyout-right a:hover +ul,
.blog-drop-down >a:hover+.Blog,
li.drop-down>a:hover +.drop-down-ul,
.images-drop-down>a:hover +.Images,
.mega-drop-down a:hover+.mega-menu,
li.flyout-mega>a:hover +.flyout-mega-wrap{
 display:block;
}
/*responsive*/
 @media (min-width:767px){
 .exo-menu > li > a{
 display:block;
 padding: 20px 22px;
 }
.mega-menu, .flyout-mega-wrap, .Images, .Blog,.flyout-right>ul,
.flyout-left>ul, li.drop-down>ul{
  position:absolute;
}
 .flyout-right>ul{
 left: 100%;
 }
 .flyout-left>ul{
 right: 100%;
}
 }
@media (max-width:767px){

 .exo-menu {
  min-height: 58px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
 }
 
 .exo-menu > li > a{
  width:100% ;
     display:none ;
 
 }
 .exo-menu > li{
  width:100%;
 }
 .display.exo-menu > li > a{
   display:block ;
    padding: 20px 22px;
 }
 
.mega-menu, .Images, .Blog,.flyout-right>ul,
.flyout-left>ul, li.drop-down>ul{
  position:relative;
}

}
a.toggle-menu{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 27px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #23364B;
    top: 0px;
}





#rollover {position:relative}
#rollover li a { text-decoration:none;}

#rollover li a span {
visibility:hidden;
display:block;
position:absolute;
/**adjust disjointed image position in % or px where desired**/
 top: 0%;
 
  right: 200%;
  width: 200px;


color:#666;
padding: 0px;
}

#rollover li a:hover span,
#rollover li a:active span,
#rollover li a:focus span { visibility:visible; }

#rollover li a:hover,
#rollover li a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
color:#FF6600;
visibility:visible; }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #rollover li a span {
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px auto 5px 20px;
    width: 28%;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
 
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



</head>

<body class="background">
  <div class="content">
  
  <ul class="exo-menu">

<!--HOME LINK-->

   <li><img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Experiment_%28website%29_logo.svg/320px-Experiment_%28website%29_logo.svg.png"></li>

<!--PRODUCTS LINK-->
   
   <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> PRODUCTS</a>
    <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu">
     <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <h4 class="row mega-title">Feature</h4>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rUk36pd-LbM/VcLb48X4f-I/AAAAAAAAGCI/Y_UxBAgEqwA/s1600/Magento_themes.jpg">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
         <h4 class="row mega-title">Mega Items</h4>
        <ul class="stander">
         
           
           
           <ul id="rollover">
    <li><a href="#">TEST 1<span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Cordell_Bank_National_Marine_Sanctuary_-_panoramio.jpg" style="width:100%;"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TEST 2<span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Monkey_Bizniz_Drama_Queen.jpg" style="width:100%;"></span></a></li>
</ul>
         
         <li><a class="view-more btn- btn-sm" href="#">View more</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4 class="row mega-title">Description</h4>
        <ul class="description">
         <li><a href="#">Women</a>
          <span>Description of Women</span>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Men</a>
           <span>Description of men Cloths</span>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Kids</a>
           <span>Description of Kids Cloths</span>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Others</a>
           <span>Description of Others Cloths</span>
         </li>
         <li>
         <a class="view-more btn btn-sm " href="#">View more</a>
            
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
       <h4 class="row mega-title">Icon + Description</h4>
        <ul class="icon-des">
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Web</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>Mobile</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-h"></i>Responsive</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>Desktop</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>UI/UX</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
       
      </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
   </li> 

<!--RETAIL LINK-->
    
   <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> RETAIL</a>
    <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu">
     <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <h4 class="row mega-title">Feature</h4>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rUk36pd-LbM/VcLb48X4f-I/AAAAAAAAGCI/Y_UxBAgEqwA/s1600/Magento_themes.jpg">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
         <h4 class="row mega-title">Standers</h4>
        <ul class="stander">
         <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Computer</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">laptop</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Camera</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">I pad</a></li>
         <li><a class="view-more btn- btn-sm" href="#">View more</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4 class="row mega-title">Description</h4>
        <ul class="description">
         <li><a href="#">Women</a>
          <span>Description of Women</span>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Men</a>
           <span>Description of men Cloths</span>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Kids</a>
           <span>Description of Kids Cloths</span>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Others</a>
           <span>Description of Others Cloths</span>
         </li>
         <li>
         <a class="view-more btn btn-sm " href="#">View more</a>
            
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
       <h4 class="row mega-title">Icon + Description</h4>
        <ul class="icon-des">
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Web</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>Mobile</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-h"></i>Responsive</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>Desktop</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>UI/UX</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
       
      </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
   </li> 



<!--BLOG LINK-->
   
   <li class="blog-drop-down"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> Blog</a>
    <div class="Blog animated fadeIn">
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-VG_e0pKfrDo/VcLb6JwZqfI/AAAAAAAAGCk/8ZgA9kZqTQ8/s1600/images3.jpg">
      <div class="blog-des">
     <h4 class="blog-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod 
       tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
       nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
       Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate. </p>
       <a class="view-more btn- btn-sm" href="#">Read More</a>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-hUt5FrdZHio/VcLb5dlwTBI/AAAAAAAAGCU/UUH5N1JkoQc/s1600/images1.jpg">
      <div class="blog-des">
      <h4 class="blog-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod 
       tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
       nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
       Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate. </p>
         <a class="view-more btn- btn-sm" href="#">Read More</a>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-A7U1uPlSq6Y/VcLb5kKHCkI/AAAAAAAAGCc/7WghyndTEuY/s1600/images2.jpg">
      <div class="blog-des">
      <h4 class="blog-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod 
       tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
       nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
       Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate. </p>
         <a class="view-more btn- btn-sm" href="#">Read More</a>
      </div>
     </div>
      
     
    </div>
   </li>

<!--SALE LINK-->
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i> SALE</a></li>

<!--ABOUT LINK-->
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> ABOUT US</a></li>



<!--CONTACT LINK-->
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
    <div class="contact">
   
    </div>
   </li>
   <a href="#" class="toggle-menu visible-xs-block">|||</a>  
 </ul>
  
  
  </div>
```

Comment: why not setting the original pic's SRC according to the hovered link?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this.  My goal is to have a "default" image but it have it change, depending upon which link is hovered.